# Joomla Get subcategories of custom parent category

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.1

I have a category ID and wan't to display all the subcategories. Show should I do that in Joomla?

I've tried the following

```
$catID = JRequest::getVar('id');
$categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content');
$cat = $categories->get($catID);
$children = JCategoryNode::getChildren($cat);
printObject($children);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: what is $children? you dont define it anywhere in the shown code.

Comment: @PatrickEvans sorry, i forgot one line $children = JCategoryNode::getChildren($cat); (code edited)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getChildren` is not a static function, you call it off the category object that you get from `get`, which should be of type JCategoryNode.

```
$catID = JRequest::getVar('id');
$categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content');
$cat = $categories->get($catID);
$children = $cat->getChildren();
print_r($children);
```

[JCategorNode api](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Application/JCategoryNode.html#getChildren)

Comment: Thank you very much. So no ai can use any JCategoryNode methods on the $categories var? Like getNumItems, getSibling etc, right?

Comment: No, $categories is a instance of JCategories, you can use the JCategoryNode methods on $cat though and any of the $children as they will be JCategoryNode as well.

Answer (score 0):

As of Joomla! 3.9 as well as Joomla! 4 you should use something like this:

```
private static function getCatChildren($id)
{
    $categories = \Joomla\CMS\Categories\Categories::getInstance('component_name');
    $cat        = $categories->get($id);
    return  $cat->getChildren();
}
```